# How to remove sidebar to make web page more responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a web design that includes one sidebar and article part. While re-sizing web page, sidebar should be disappear and new button should be appear on the right. However, I donot understand how to disappear sidebar and put new one on the right.  How can I do?

Page

```
________  _____                                  _________  ___
|      |  |   |   after re-sizing viewport,      |        | | |
|      |  |   |   I should get this web page --> |        | |_|
|      |  |   |                                  |        | 
|      |  |   |                                  |        |
|______|  |___|                                  |________|
```

I have implemented index html like;

```
<link   href="css/large-page-design.css"    
        rel="stylesheet"    
        type="text/css" />

<link   href="css/medium-page-design.css"  
        rel="stylesheet"    
        type="text/css" 
        media="only screen and (min-width: 700px ) and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-height: 500px)">
```

And, in `index.html`, I have filled sidebar content like;

```
<div id="sidebar">

    <div id="page-information">
            <h1>My web page</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- other two div elements with its content-->
</div>
```

In addition to html, I have declared `large-page-design.css` as;

```
@import url('sidebar.css') screen;

#sidebar{
    top:0px;
    height: 519px; 
    width: 325px;
    float: right;
    background: none; 
    position:relative; 
}
```

and, in `sidebar.css`, I have;

```
#page-information{
    background-image:url(...);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 75px;
    width: 300px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hide the side-bar using media-queries and show a button using `display property`

add this in large-page-design.css

```
#sideButton{
   display:none;
   }
```

add this in medium-page-design.css

```
 #sidebar{
     display:none;
   }
   #sideButton{
     display:block;
    }
```

Have a `#sideButton` element in Html

Comment: should write it in css or html file?

Comment: @Hevan  you want the sidebar to disappear in tablets?

Comment: Yes I want exactly what you said.

Comment: I have a different question; Can I do like `@media (max-width: 700px) {import medium.css}`?

Comment: @Hevan i edited answer..Do read about media queries..they are easy to understand as well as easy to use..And about the other q in comment..
no you cannot use it that way.More over `Max-width:700px` reflects for mostly mobile devices..I was giving an example with the resolution.